# JQuery next().attr() not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

Here is my JS code

```
var inputid = $("#"+parentId).next().attr('id');
var tdid = $("#"+inputid).next().attr('id');
```

Here 'parentId' is a parameter in my function. Basically parentId is the id of a td, after that td I have a hidden text field then another td.

td->hiddenfiled->td

First of all am getting the id of first td, by using that id am getting hidden field's id, then by using hidden field's id am getting next td's id.

This is working fine in all browsers except IE. when I alerted it it is giving 'undefined'.

Here is my html

```
<td id="tone_one" class="ttd_class class_tone" height="25px;" style="border-left: 3px solid #000000; border-right: 3px solid #000000;" align=center valign=bottom bgcolor="#ffffff" >&nbsp;</td><input type="hidden" id="tone_one_txt" name="tone_one_txt">

<td id="tone_two" class="ttd_class class_ttwo" height="25px;"  style="border-left: 3px solid #000000; border-right: 3px solid #000000;" align=center valign=bottom bgcolor="#ffffff" >&nbsp;</td><input type="hidden" id="tone_two_txt" name="tone_two_txt">
```

Am new to JQuery. Pls help.

Thanks

Comment: Please include your html.  A hidden text field as a sibling of a `td` is not valid.

Comment: You could just pass a selector to `next()` to skip the hidden field: `$("#"+parentId).next('td').attr('id');`

Comment: @jbabey: That's not how `.next` works. If you pass a selector, it will select the next sibling **only if** it matches the selector. It won't select the next sibling that matches the selector.

Comment: That's invalid markup.  You shouldn't have `<td></td><input /><td></td>`.  Can you put the hidden inputs inside the `<td>` elements.

Comment: @FelixKling oh that's right, `nextAll()` is what I was thinking.

Comment: IE is correctly fixing the html, resulting in the hidden input getting moved elsewhere because it's invalid there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your HTML is not correctly interpreted by IE. Just put the hidden input fields in the same `td` and the try the code below. It will work in all browsers:

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="tone_one" class="ttd_class class_tone" height="25px;" style="border-left: 3px solid #000000; border-right: 3px solid #000000;" align=center valign=bottom bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;
            <input type="hidden" id="tone_one_txt" name="tone_one_txt">
        </td>
        <td id="tone_two" class="ttd_class class_ttwo" height="25px;" style="border-left: 3px solid #000000; border-right: 3px solid #000000;" align=center valign=bottom bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;
            <input type="hidden" id="tone_two_txt" name="tone_two_txt">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
var inputid = $("#"+parentId).children().attr('id');
var tdid = $("#"+inputid).closest('td').next().attr('id');
```

Answer (score -2):

Use like this.

```
var inputid = $("#parentId").next().attr('id');
```

Comment: Why would the `.next` function have a property `attr`? This is completely wrong.

Comment: i am not giving property to .next(), Do not combine next & attr into one thing.. it will work like $("#parentId").attr('id');

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `$("#parentId").next` is a function. So by accessing `$("#parentId").next.attr`, you are accessing the `attr` property of the function `$("#parentId").next`. Since such a property does not exist, this code is incorrect.

Comment: by accessing $("#parentId").next.attr , We will get attribute of $("#parentId")

Comment: `$("#parentId").next.attr` **does not exist!** `.next` is a **function**: http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: As i have not implement or run above query but I am Sure in jquery  We can use as many events as we want to use in one function.

Comment: Read up on how to use the `.next()` method (note the parentheses) http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: Now that you have changed it to a function call, you posted what the OP already uses, and it does not work for him. *"Cant We use like this?"* Well, that's not how you posted it originally. You were missing `()`.

Comment: that was just i have said for reference that we can use 2 functions or methods together..

Comment: My Actual Mean To Say Like He should Use  $("#parentId")  Instead   $("#"+parentId)

Comment: But why? Maybe the variable `parentId` contains the actual ID. You are only making assumptions here. As you can see in the HTML the OP posted, the ID of the table cells are `tone_on` and `tone_two`, not `parentId`.

Comment: Yupp... that may be possible, right.. I will be carefull next time before Answer.. Thanks :)  @FelixKling